# Using is_cli_request() is necessary for cron job in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Using Codeigniter 2.2.0 for my project. Is `$this->input->is_cli_request()` validation is necessary for a cron job?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to protect your cronjob not to execute when someone type the URL in their browser. However if you don't have any problem running your cronjob invoked by anyone then can avoid this check.

Refer https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It recommented to run cron jobs with command line.

There are many reasons for running CodeIgniter from the command-line, but they are not always obvious.

- Run your cron-jobs without needing to use wget or curl
- Make your cron-jobs inaccessible from being loaded in the URL by checking for `$this->input->is_cli_request()`
- Make interactive "tasks" that can do things like set permissions, prune cache folders, run backups, etc.
- Integrate with other applications in other languages. For example, a random C++ script could call one command and run code in your models!

More info read [here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html)

But you also can prevent calling from URL in your server.